# Why should I implement toString method for my Object?

Tags: java, object, tostring

Besides printing stuffs for the console what other use have you found for toString() method for your objects?

Comment: related http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2653268/auto-generating-tostring-method

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It makes a convenient debugging aid when you just want to have a quick look at the contents of an object.

Answer (score 4):

I use it **only** for debugging purpose. For functional requirements I always implement a well named method like `String toExportFormat()`.

You will understand why I do so the first time you try to figure out where your output method is getting called. If you use `toString()` somewhere in your code, you will hardly be able to find all places, because each and every object implements this method. If you use a specialized method, it's very easy to find the places where it is called. And you can refer to this method inside your `toString()` method - it's not even more work.

Answer (score 1):

Lots of frameworks use it to provide default representations of your objects, e.g., labels for elements of a tree in Swing.

Besides, just having something readable on the console is enough, because logging is FAR easier when you can rely on the `toString()`.