# Print all bean properties in EL without need to override toString() every time

Tags: jsp, debugging, el, tostring

I have a list/map of beans in EL, or at least I assume it is and I'm fed up with spending hours going through trying to work out which sections belong to each other. So I print it plain like `${example}`.

> football.beans.FootballFixture@72bec69[match=football.domain.FootballMatch@773aa1d5[id=360496,competition=PREMIERSHIP,seasonId=2011,groupName=,roundType=,roundNumber=,matchPeriod=FULL_TIME,matchDay=3,venueId=33,venue=White Hart Lane,venueCity=London,homeTeamId=t6,awayTeamId=t43,homeScore=1,awayScore=5,scorers=[football.domain.Score@3d5bed54[567825,AWAY,2011-08-28 14:05:05.0,34,GOAL,Dzeko,,FIRST_HALF

Currently I am overriding `toString()` on my beans every time. It'd be great to have something similar to PHP's `print_r` in JSP. Anybody know how to stop my eternal headache caused by this problem.

Comment: This is possibly not a direct solution to your question, but you may want to check out ReflectionToStringBuilder. Please see this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3149951/java-tostring-tostringbuilder-not-sufficient-wont-traverse

Comment: @JB Nizet use the debugger? I'm a php dev not a java, but my new job means i'll be doing java. At least from a front end perspective. So i guess i can google this myself but any pointers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Import the Jackson JSON library and do something like this (assuming "myList" is the list/map you already have defined):

```
 ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
 System.out.println( mapper.defaultPrettyPrintingWriter().writeValueAsString(myList) );
```

This would print out your complete list object as a string to standard out.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Pojomatic lib.

If you use maven, add dependency to `pom.xml`.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.pojomatic</groupId>
    <artifactId>pojomatic</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Then add `@AutoProperty` annotation to class you want to read like `PostVo.java`.

And, override toString method like this:

```
@Override
 public String toString() {
     return Pojomatic.toString (this);
}
```

You can override `hashCode()` and `equals(Object obj)`.

```
@Override
 public boolean equals(Object obj) {
     return Pojomatic.equals (this, obj);
}

@Override
 public int hashCode() {
     return Pojomatic.hashCode (this);
}
```