# Could ThreadLocal<AtomicInteger> possibly be useful?

Tags: java, multithreading, atomic

So I just [saw someone try to use](https://github.com/Bukkit/CraftBukkit/pull/1168/files#diff-fe5bc4ce713fa653092be2a451805f18R226) a `ThreadLocal<AtomicInteger>` in some Java code.
Now, for the linked code, that's clearly useless, among other problems which caused the request to be denied.

And it seems like it would always be useless: `AtomicInteger` (from the java.util.concurrent.atomic package) is designed for multithread access, and `ThreadLocal` makes each thread have its own value, so why even use it?

My question is: **Is there any situation in which a `ThreadLocal<AtomicInteger>` would be useful?**

Comment: Not an interesting comment - but I really can't think of any. I agree with your reasoning and think that it excludes any situations where ThreadLocal<AtomicInteger> would be useful.

Comment: Unless using Reflection, there is no way to access the threadlocal of another thread.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, we may come up with a legitimate scenario:

1. we need a thread-local instance of `AtomicInteger` at the start of each task;
2. we proceed to distribute this object among several other threads, for example child threads forked by the main task thread.

Without assessing the totality of the context where this appears, we cannot judge.

Comment: 1. Is this saying we might need to do it because we might need to do it? 2. But in this context would using ThreadLocal to begin with be sensible.

Although I agree that it's difficult to rule things out without a clear context.

Comment: @selig If all this happens in server code, each client request is served by its own thread in isolation, and that main thread starts its own thread group and distributes the `AtomicInteger`, which may need to be reused from previous tasks (it isn't a fresh object each time). Yes, it is a stretch, but that doesn't matter: once you have the need, you have it, and you are not guilty of it.

Comment: Yeah, this sounds like a legitimate scenario (multithreaded server, one thread/client handing off to multiple workers). I'll hold off on accepting in case a better answer comes along.

Answer (score 6):

Suppose we need an integer counter per thread. ThreadLocal can work only with objects so logically we need to use an int wrapper - Integer

```
ThreadLocal<Integer> count = new ThreadLocal<>();
...
count.set(count.get() + 1);
```

alternatavely we can use AtomicInteger, not because it's thread safe but because it's mutable

```
ThreadLocal<AtomicInteger> count = new ThreadLocal<>();
...
count.get().incrementAndGet();
```

Version 2 has a much better performance than version 1 which is a real performance killer

Comment: Good point. I use AtomicReference<T> to pass a result object from code in a Runnable back to the invoker - not because I need the atomicity, but because I need a mutable reference and I'm too lazy to create a class for that.

Comment: So just for the sake of having a well-written wrapper? Maybe the stdlib should provide a MutableInteger class or something, then.

Comment: `AtomicInteger` uses `volatile` and some synchronization under the hood. So it's not clear to me how its overhead compares to boxing overhead of `Integer` in this case. Did you check the "version 1 is a real performance killer" statement with proper benchmark?

Comment: I tested with JMH. https://github.com/tkobayas/jmh-example/blob/master/threadlocal-atomicinteger/src/main/java/com/github/tkobayas/jmh/example/ThreadLocalBenchmark.java

~~~
Benchmark                               Mode    Cnt    Score   Error  Units
ThreadLocalBenchmark.testAtomicInteger    ss  20000   92.736 ± 1.461  us/op
ThreadLocalBenchmark.testInteger          ss  20000  111.812 ± 2.375  us/op
~~~

AtomicInteger is faster.

Answer (score 2):

I think there are only exotic reasons for `ThreadLocal<AtomicInteger>`. There might be situations where the `ThreadLocal` is not the only reference to the `AtomicInteger` so that more threads can access it. When you find yourself in such a situation, I think you better have a careful look at your design...

In case you do **not** need the thread safety of `AtomicInteger` but merely its mutability, I prefer using an `int[]`. Less overhead then `AtomicInteger` combined with full control:

```
ThreadLocal<int[]> count = new ThreadLocal<>();
...
count.set(new int[1]);
...
count.get()[0] = 42;
...
count.get()[0] += 4711;
```