# Write toString() once and for all?

Tags: java, tostring

I want to have all of my classes implement `toString()` the same way using Java reflection. There are two ways I came up with.

1. Create a base class such as `MyObject` overriding `toString()` and all my classes would extend it, but I'm not sure if it'd be an overkill.
2. Use Eclipse to generate the overridden `toString()` for each class. The downside of it is that there'd be a lot of code redundancy.

Which is the preferred method? If you go with Eclipse templates, is there a way to auto-generate it when you do New > Class, instead of having to do Source > Generate toString() every time?

Comment: Such a `toString()` method would be very generic if it works with all classes. I can't see that it would be much more useful than the default `toString()` that gives the class and an identifier for the object. What are you trying to achieve / what problem are you trying to solve by doing this?

Comment: It's just for debugging purposes. I find it really helpful that eclipse displays a reference variable's value using toString() when you hover your mouse over it.

Comment: See also [Auto-generating toString Method](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2653268/auto-generating-tostring-method)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As Harkness says, use commons-lang ReflectionToStringBuilder.

Rather than have a base class, I'd use AOP such as [aspectj](http://eclipse.org/aspectj) to inject this implementation into all of your classes at compile time.

Another option is to use a tool like [ASM](http://asm.objectweb.org) to transform your classes at compile time to inject toString methods. Both approaches use the same basic concepts, ASM being a more 'raw' version of class file modification.

Comment: +1 I don't think that violating the "is-a" relationship is a big deal.  The fact is that all of his classes share common functionality (the exact same implementation of toString) so making them derive from a base class is acceptable.  However, he mentioned that this is for debugging purposes so using AOP will be easier to remove when he's finished.  Nice answer.

Comment: Thanks guys. Could you elaborate on AOP? Can I do it without using annotations?

Comment: the nice thing about AOP is the source code has absolutely no modifications, and is completely unaware of it. See http://eclipse.org/aspectj/ and the thousands of tutorials on aspectj

Answer (score 3):

See [ToStringBuilder](http://commons.apache.org/lang/api-2.5/org/apache/commons/lang/builder/ToStringBuilder.html) and its subclass [ReflectionToStringBuilder](http://commons.apache.org/lang/api-2.5/org/apache/commons/lang/builder/ReflectionToStringBuilder.html) from [Apache Commons Lang](http://commons.apache.org/lang/). The latter would allow you to implement `toString()` generically in your base class or add it to the template:

```
public String toString() {
    return ReflectionToStringBuilder.toString(this);
}
```

Comment: I agree with this response. But we can complement explaining that Java only support simple inheritance and use it for just reuse toString() is a bad idea from OO paradigm perspective.

Comment: @Ernesto Campohermoso: I think you're seriously confused ; )   *Hermeso extends MyObject*   and *MyObject extends Object*  <-- There are exactly zero issues here, I didn't "lost" my ability to extend *MyObject* by having *MyObject extends Object*  I think "simple inheritance" doesn't mean what you think it means ; )

Comment: @CedricMartin Assume that later you really need to inheret Hermeso from  other class GenericHermeso which contain really similar behavior and/or attributes. You will need extends GenericHermeso to MyObject and then extends Hermeso to GenericHermeso. I think this is the correct way to use the OO paradigm. Other case, if you are using a framework that doesn't have POJO development you sure will need to inherit form Servlet, Thread, Action, and son on ;)

Answer (score 3):

Option 1 is a really bad idea, because it imposes an "is a" constraint to your implementations for no good reason, and every one of your classes must inherit from the same base class. This is unlikely to even be possible.

Option 2 is also a bad idea - you'd have the same code repeated in *every* class - a maintenance nightmare and adding no value.

A better option is to use a utility class:

```
public class MyUtils {

    public static String toString(Object object) {
        // your reflection impl here
    }

}

public class MyClass {

    ...

    public String toString() {
        return MyUtils.toString(this);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use lombok to do this as well, see:

http://www.projectlombok.org/features/ToString.html

If you are interested in additionally generating all getters, setters, toString, hashCode, and equals, you can use the `@Data` annotation, see:

http://www.projectlombok.org/features/Data.html