# Generic "quasi toString()" using Java Class reflection

Tags: java, reflection

I have been trying to create a robust code that prints out any Java class for debugging. For that, I use reflections.
In order to protect against recursive definition such as "Boolean contains static final Boolean TRUE", I ignore fields equal to their parents.
I use String += just out of laziness. It doesn't have to be efficient.

Yet, is there a nicer way to do recursive description of objects with reflections?

```
public String reflectionShowFields(Object parentObject) {
    String stringData = "";

    for (Field field:parentObject.getClass().getFields()) {
        try {
            Class<?> type = field.getType();
            String typeSimpleName = type.getSimpleName();
            Object fieldValue = field.get(parentObject);
            String fieldName = field.getName();
            if (type.isPrimitive() || type.isEnum() || CharSequence.class.isAssignableFrom(type)) {
                stringData += String.format("%s: %s\n", fieldName, fieldValue);
            } else if (Iterable.class.isAssignableFrom(type)) {
                stringData += String.format(">>> %s[%s]: \n", fieldName, typeSimpleName);
                for (Object item:(Iterable)fieldValue) {
                    stringData += reflectionShowFields(item);
                }
                stringData += String.format("<<< %s[%s]: \n", fieldName, typeSimpleName);
            } else if (!fieldValue.equals(parentObject)) {
                stringData += String.format(">>> %s[%s]: %s \n--------\n", fieldName, typeSimpleName, fieldValue.toString());
                stringData+= reflectionShowFields(fieldValue);
                stringData += String.format("<<< %s[%s]: \n", fieldName, typeSimpleName);
            }
        } catch (IllegalAccessException ignored) {}
    }
    return stringData;
}
```

Comment: Can't eclipse generate a toString() for you? This seems like more trouble than it's worth.

Comment: See also [Auto-generating toString Method](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2653268/auto-generating-tostring-method)

Answer (score 4):

You could use Apache commons-lang ReflectionToStringBuilder https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/builder/ReflectionToStringBuilder.html

Comment: Could have worked if I could easily join libs :( I am running Android so I have to be thin on libs and thin on footprint. Since the whole thing is for debugging, I better not waste precious memory when the final product doesn't need it. Thanks. S.M

Answer (score 2):

I don't think this is going to work.

- Ignoring fields "that are equal to their parents" won't work.  What if you have an `A` that refers to a `B` that refers back to the `A`.
- You *want* to know about the cycles, and also the shared nodes in a DAG.
- Iterating an `Iterable` can have side-effects, or it might never terminate, or it might throw exceptions.
- Producing a readable rendering of an arbitrary graph is likely to really hard.
- This is going to be an order of magnitude slower than a hand-built `toString()` method.

But think about it this way.  If this was a good idea, there would be high profile 3rd-party libraries that did this kind of thing.  And we'd all be using them already.  It turns out that there ARE 3rd-party libraries, but you'd hardly call them high profile.

---

Incidentally, you could use JAXB or a JSON binding to render your POJOs as text.  That achieves the same ends ...

---

Finally, your example of Boolean with a static field of type Boolean is not apropos.  You wouldn't want to render static fields when displaying an instance.

Comment: Agree, had to fix it so that it works. Had to give up recursive types. If you have a recursive type that doesn't define toString() - tough luck. It's a pity but I didn't want to put too much time on debug tools.
As for 3rd parties etc. I prefer not. I am a lib so I better not mess the user with other libs. Also, it's Android. I need to be memory skinny. So for me, it's only POJO.